# Shell command to cut the url into phase

Tags: awk, grep, cut

I want to cut my url `https://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/` into `https://jenkins.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com:443`. I have tried several ways to handle it

tried in these ways

```
$ echo https://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/ | cut -d"/" -f3 | cut -d"/" -f5
jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com
```

Input:

```
https://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/
```

Expected Output:

```
https://jenkins.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com:443
```

Comment: Could you please wrap your samples in code tags as it is not clear as of now.

Comment: If you want to "cut" the input (ie. remove parts of the input), then where does the `:443` come from?

Comment: 1st case : echo https://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/ | cut -d"/" -f3 | cut -d"/" -f2
jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com

Comment: @Kamil. I need to add that :443 string to end of url whcih is mandatory one.

Comment: So what happened to `crumbtest2`? What should the result be for a random string? What is the allowed range of inputs? How does the output get's produced? I believe you want to [use sed with substitution](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1) and write a proper regex to match the input, learn regexes with [crosswords](https://regexcrossword.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written based on shown samples only.

```
awk '{sub(/jenkins-[^.]*/,"jenkins");sub(/\/$/,":443")} 1' Input_file
```

Or with `echo` try:

```
echo "https://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/" |
awk '{sub(/jenkins-[^.]*/,"jenkins");sub(/\/$/,":443")} 1'
```

Explanation: sending echo commands output to awk command as an Input then using sub function of awk first substituting everything from keyword Jenkins till dot comes with string Jenkins. Then substituting last occurrence of / with :443 in line.

Comment: Ravi, Thanks for the command and i tried out "echo "https://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/" | awk '{sub(/\/$/,":443")} 1'
https://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com:443" But i want the output like https://jenkins.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com:443 without crumbtest2 string

Comment: @KandikuppaVinod, sure could you please try my edit echo command once?

Comment: Awesome. It is perfectly working. Thank you so much and also please explain awk code?

Comment: @KandikuppaVinod, your welcome I added explanation too please do lemme know in case of any queries.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, Thanks for the explanation. I was trying to avoid jenkins string as well in the command like 'Expected o/p: https://origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com:443.'  Please help me

Comment: My apologies Ravinder. Thank you for your patience and solution. I got my answer.

Comment: @KandikuppaVinod, np :) Happy to help, you could also up-vote this answer buddy cheers and happy learning :)

Answer (score 0):

`perl` one-liner that looks up the appropriate port number based on scheme, instead of assuming https:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "https://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/" \
                "http://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/"  \
                "ftp://jenkins-crumbtest2.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com/"   |
    perl -F: -lane 'print s!-crumbtest2|/$!!rg, ":", scalar getservbyname($F[0], "tcp")'
https://jenkins.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com:443
http://jenkins.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com:80
ftp://jenkins.origin-ctc-core-nonprod.com:21
```